# Defining origin when calculating center of mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics

What rules are there concerning where to place the origin when calculating center of mass? Take this simple example:

$0.5$ kg and $2.0$ kg, connected by a massless rod $0.5$ m long rod.

By using the common formula $\frac{\sum_i^n m_i\ y_i}{\Sigma m}$ one gets two different results, depending on which of the two masses is chosen as the origin. Specifically $0.40$ m and $0.10$ m. The right choice here is obvious due to common sense, but my textbook doesn't say anything about why. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing something obvious. The position you calculate is the position *relative to the chosen origin*. In one case, it's 40 cm from the lighter mass; in the other case, 10 cm from the heavier mass. Since the two masses (the two chosen origins) were 50 cm apart, that's the same answer...

Answer (score -1):

See, according to your results, when you took the 0.5 kg mass as origin, the answer was 0.40m. But in the next one, you made a slight mistake. Because it's **-0.10m** from right(2kg mass). So both the answers are correct. You just have to keep in mind that the distances you put in the equation are *relative* to the origin you selected.[image]
[image]

Comment: We have MathJax running in the site so you can typeset mathematics in a LaTeX math-mode alike language. Images if text or mathematics are strongly discouraged.